# jQuery find closets elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, css-selectors

I'm looking the way to find and select the 5 closest "li" (two, three, four, five and six) with class "active" Any idea?

```
<li class="one">Hello</li>
<li class="two">Hello</li>
<li class="three">Hello</li>
<li class="four active">Hello</li>
<li class="five">Hello</li>
<li class="six">Hello</li>
<li class="seven">Hello</li>
<li class="eight">Hello</li>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you really want the 5 closest items if one is `active`? Or do you just want one,two and three?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index` and `slice` methods:

```
var $li = $('li');
var ind = $li.filter('.active').index(); 
if ( ind-2 < 0 ) ind = 0;

$li.slice(ind-2, ind+3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dc8Xu/

Comment: you should probably check for negative indexes for that slice method... `slice(-1, 3)` isn't gonna work. oh... and it would be ind+2, right?

Comment: @mayhewr Yes, I was updating the code, with ind+2 it will select four elements.

Comment: if ind is 4, 4-2 to 4+2 is 2 to 6... 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (5 elements).  Also, if ind is 1 you should probably go up to ind+4 so that you get all 5.

Comment: @mayhewr http://jsfiddle.net/NWJ6h/,  OP wants to select 2 elements after and 2 elements before the active element, not necessary 5 elements.

Comment: did he... tell you that? he told me "5 closest"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $a = ​$( ".active" ),
    $all = $a.​​​​​​siblings().andSelf(),
    i = $all.index( $a ),
    i0 = i < 2 ? 0 
    : i + 5 > $all.length ? $all.length - 5 : i - 2;
    $five = $all.slice( i0, i0 + 5 );
```

$five is your collection.

Comment: Yep... this works... Not your standard syntax and the readability is questionable... but...works never-the-less

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest code sample I've ever given... but does the trick :)

```
var activeItem = $('li.active');

activeItem.prev('li').addClass('active').prev('li').addClass('active');
activeItem.next('li').addClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
```

I'm utilizing a feature of jQuery here called chaining. This means that the functions I've used actually return the object itself that the action was performed on. So the `addClass()` function actually returns the item we added the class to. This allows us to "chain" functions together.

#### [See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/JbPTD/1/)

Reference -

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have 5 results:

```
var length = $('li').length;
var start = $('.active').index() - 2;
start = start + 5 > length ? length - 6 : start;
start = start < 0 ? 0 : start;
var result = $('li').slice(start, start + 5);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

A single line answer

```
$('li.active').prevAll().andSelf().slice(-3).add('li.active + *').add('li.active + * + *').css('color','red');
```

Explanation:
First get all the elements before the active item with [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) then add the active item itself, and only return the last 3 items with the [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function. Add the items after the `li.active` with the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function containing the special [`+`](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) selector

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nhP33/)